# Execute a web api method several times based on time constraint

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have an assignment to access a web API to get a token and use this token as an input to call another web API. Token expires after 60 seconds so I have to again call first web API to get new token and then use this new token to access my second web API.
In normal scenario it is working fine but some time second API takes more time to execute and token expires.

I have used `HttpClient` class to call web API. How should I handle token expiration time constraint before calling another web API. I want to make it more generic.
I have written following code.

```
public override bool CallAPI()
    {
        try
        {
            bool isSPAdded = false;
            int counter = 0;
            do
            {
                 Uri uri = new Uri(_settings.HostUrl + "/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token");
                 var requestContent = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&client_id=admin-cli&grant_type=password", _settings.UserName, _settings.Password);
                 StringContent _requestContent = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                _response = _client.PostAsync(uri, _requestContent).Result;

                if (_response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format(_settings.HostUrl + "/auth/admin/realms/{0}/clients", Node.OrgId));
                    _requestContent = new StringContent(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    _response = _client.PostAsync(uri, _requestContent).Result;
                    if (_response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        isSPAdded = _response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                counter++;
            } while (_response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized && _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result == "Bearer" && counter < 2);

            return isSPAdded;
        }
    }
```

I have used do while loop to retry it if token expires.
Please suggest the best approach for same.

Comment: Can you show us the code of your current approach / what you have tried so far? It is easier to help you if we have an existing situation to work with.

Comment: Just check token validity before call and refresh it if needed + catch unauthorized response/exception and also refresh the token

Comment: Should I use Timer  or Stopwatch class to validate token ? Will it be good to use these heavy objects in web API?

Comment: Can I use recursion for token validation if not valid then call again n again ?There can be issue, method can be stuck into infinite loop.

Comment: I am facing similar problem, Output of Function1 will be input of Function2. If output of Function1 is not valid then call again Function1 before calling Function2. I think recursion is not a good option.

Comment: Do you own the authorization endpoint and/or do you have the possibility of using refresh tokens? It's probably easier to use IdentityModel's TokenClient for this (since your auth endpoint is OpenID): https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel which gives you some helpers to work with token refreshing and expiration

Comment: github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel is not serving purpose. Dow e have any design pattern for this?